# Incrementing numeric parameter in a URL parameter string?

Tags: ruby, string

I've had a look round and can't find what I need on Stack Overflow, and was wondering if someone had a simple solution.

I want to find a parameter within a URL and increment its value, so, as an example:

```
?kws=&pstc=&cty=&prvnm=1
```

I want to be able to locate the `prvnm` parameter no matter where it is in the string and increment its value by 1.

I know I could split the parameters into an array, find the key, increment it and write it back but that seems rather long winded and wondered if someone else had any ideas!

Comment: long winded? `str.split(?&).map{|| ar=s.split(?=);ar[]= if ar[]; ar.join()}.join()` ? really, that's much like it, after filling some tiny bits of course

Comment: Take advantage of the built-in class [URI](http://www.omniref.com/docs/ruby/stdlib/2.0.0-p247/classes/URI.html) to take apart, and rebuild, URLs. It'll correctly handle encoding for you. There's also the [Addressable::URI](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/) gem, which is more full-featured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require "uri"

url = "http://example.com/?kws=&pstc=&cty=&prvnm=1"

def new_url(url)
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  hsh = Hash[URI.decode_www_form(uri.query)]
  hsh['prvnm'] = hsh['prvnm'].next
  uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(hsh).to_s
  uri.to_s
end

new_url(url) # => "http://example.com/?kws=&pstc=&cty=&prvnm=2"
```

Answer (score 2):

There are already four answers, so I had to come up with something a little different:

```
s = "?kws=&pstc=&cty=&prvnm=1"

head, sep, tail = s.partition(/(?<=[?&]prvnm=)\d+/)
head + (sep.to_i + 1).to_s + tail # => "?kws=&pstc=&cty=&prvnm=2"
```

- ['String#partition'](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-partition) returns an array of three strings `[head, sep, tail]`, `such that head + sep + tail => s`, where `sep`arator is `partition`'s argument, which can be a string or a `regex`.
- We want the separator to be the digits following `&prvnm=`.  We therefore use a `regex` with `\d+` preceeded by the aforementioned string which we want to treat as having zero length, so it will not be included in the separator.  That calls for a "positive look-behind":  `(?<=&prvnm=)`.  `\d+` is "greedy", so it take all consequetive digits.
- For the given value of `s`, `head, sep, tail = s.partition(/(?<=&prvnm=)(\d+)/)
  => ["?kws=&pstc=&cty=&prvnm=", "1", ""]`.

Edit: my thanks to @quetzalcoatl for pointing out that I needed to change `(?<=&prvnm=)` in my regex to what I have now, as what I had would fail when `?prvnm=` was at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
split the string by `&`  
then iterate over the parts  
then split each part by `=` and inspect the results  
  when found `prvnm`, parse the integer and increment it  
  then join the bits by '='  
then join the parts by '&'
```

Or, use regex like:

```
/[?&]prvnm=\d+/
```

and parse the result and then do a replacement.

Or, get some URL-parsing library..

Comment: In your regex, I don't believe `[]` or `?` do anything.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: oh yes, they do. They guard against `asdasdprvnm` just like `=` guards against `prvnmasdas` keys. Of course, the regex needs to be tailored properly, like adding capture groups or marking some parts as look-behind or look-aheads, but that's not the point of an "idea".

Comment: @CarySwoveland: maybe you didn't notice that `?&` are inside a `character group`? btw. your example will fail if the URL is `?prvnm=2&kws=&pstc=&cty=`. That's why I included a chargrp. You should too!

Comment: Inside a character-class `?` is escaped to its literal meaning, so `[?&]` looks for either "?" or "&". Its equivalent is `[\?&]` but we don't need the escape (`\\`).

Comment: My mistake. Thanks to both of you for the explanation, and to quetz for noting I had made this mistake in my own answer (which I fixed).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
require 'uri'
```

Then:

1. `parsed-url=  URI.parse( ur full url)`
2. `r = CGI.parse(parsed_url.query)`

`r` is now a hash of all your query parameters.

You can easily access it by using:

```
r["prsvn"].to_i + 1
```

Comment: "ur"? Please take the time to spell "your" correctly. It's a known fact that people will disregard what you write if you can't take the time to spell correctly. In addition, learn how to do formatting on Stack Overflow and use punctuation correctly so your work is easier to read. People will downvote you for ignoring those sort of things.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
params = "?kws=&pstc=&cty=&prvnm=1"
num = params.scan(/prvnm=(\d)/)[0].join.to_i
puts num + 1
```